# stack to determine if a string of characters is a palindrome

Tags: java

I'm getting cannot find symbol error on `Stack stack = new Stack(str.length());`

Why is this not working?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/*/
    This progrma will read string and return if the string is 
    palindrome word, phrase, sentence or not. if the word is not palindrome
    the progrma will pritn out false otherwise the progrma will print out true. 
*/

public class PalindromeDemo 
{

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String str)
    {
        boolean isPal = true;
        //creating stack
       Stack stack = new Stack(str.length());
        //push all character into stack
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
            stack.push(str.charAt(i));
        }

        // now traverse str and check current character with top of stack
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = (char) stack.pop();
            // if not equal, break
            if(Character.toLowerCase(c) != Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)))
            {
                isPal = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isPal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        str = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println(isPalindrome(str));
    }

}
```

Comment: Look at the API documentation for [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), particularly the list of constructors. Notice that there is no constructor that accepts arguments.

Comment: Also suggest you search SO for "java cannot find symbol".

Comment: Consider using generics, i.e. Stack<Char> stack = new Stack<Char>(); then the stack accepts and returns Chars only and you can get rid of the nasty type cast char c = (char) stack.pop()

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting cannot find symbol error on `Stack stack = new Stack(str.length());`

It appears you forgot an import statement for `Stack`:

```
import java.util.Stack;
```

Then you would have another error, because `Stack` has only a parameterless constructor, it cannot take an `int` parameter as in your code. The fix for that is to simply drop the parameter:

```
Stack stack = new Stack();
```

Other than that, your program seems to be working, aside from some bad practices:

- You should not use raw types. Instead of `Stack`, `Stack<Character>` would be better
- According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), `Stack` is no longer recommended, you should use `Deque` and `ArrayDeque` instead
- A stack is really overkill for this task, using too much extra storage, when you could simply compare the `i`-th and `str.length() - i - 1`-th letters